# Checking User Inputs : minLength

Tags: sapui5

```
<Label required="true" text="Vorname"/>
<Input enabled="true" fieldGroupIds="Patient" id="Vorname" liveChange="_validateSaveEnablement" name="Vorname" valueLiveUpdate="true"
    value="{ 
            path : 'Vorname', 
            type : 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.String' , 
            constraints : { 
                minLength : 2,
                maxLength : 29 
            } 
    }"/>
```

It seems the `minLength`wont work. The field is required, but still accepts empty values. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type you used `sap.ui.model.odata.type.String` does in fact not support `minLength` (probably because OData doesn't support it).

You can switch your type to `sap.ui.model.type.String` to make it work.

See the following example: [plnkr.co (credit to Qualiture for the base template)](http://plnkr.co/edit/xPKDAwJz07xu8P5xndzl?p=preview) .

The first input field supports both `minLength` and `maxLength`, the second only supports `maxLength`.